# Pythonic way to map optional

Tags: python

In Java one can use `Optional.map` to conditionally transform nullable values.

```
Optional[Integer] multiplyByTwo(Optional[Integer] i) {
  return i.map(x -> x * 2);
}
```

Is there a pythonic practice for this? This seems okay

```
def multiply_by_two(i: int | None):
  return None if i is None else i * 2
```

But is less ideal when you have a scenario

```
def get_object_for_dict(d: dict):
  return SomeType(i=None if d.get('i') is None else d['i'].to_decimal())
```

Where you'd like to avoid creating the extra intermediate variable

```
def get_object_for_dict(d: dict):
  i = d.get('i')
  return SomeType(i=None if i is None else i.to_decimal())
```

Ideally, we could do

```
def get_object_for_dict(d: dict):
  return SomeType(i=map_or_none(d.get('i'), lambda x: x.to_decimal()))
```

Or if we got really fancy, we could have a python type that overrides `__getattribute__` to always return None

```
def get_object_for_dict(d: dict):
  return SomeType(i=Noneable(d.get('i')).to_decimal())
```

Or even better, have a dictionary type that supports this concept

```
def get_object_for_dict(d: NoneableDict):
  return SomeType(i=d.get('i').to_decimal())
```

Comment: I would create the intermediate variable and do the explicit conditional, Anyway, there is no direct equivalent in Python. You can if course create something like that if you want.

Comment: I don't understand, is `return val.to_decimal() if (val:=g.get('i')) else None` what do you want? (utilising the `:=` operator)

Comment: You can use the walrus operator which will create an intermediate variable, but its in the expression: `return SomeType(i=None if (val:=d.get('i')) is None else val.to_decimal())`.

Comment: To note, your first `SomeType(i=None if d.get('i') is None else d['i'].to_decimal())` is already okay. There are lots of dict lookups in python. Finding `SomeType`, `get`, `d`, `to_decimal` and all of the stuff in `SomeType.__init__` dwarf the extra lookup of `d['i']`. The only risk is `d['i']` changing in another thread between these two operations, but that would already be a threading bug anyway.

Comment: @AndrejKesely That's true, the walrus operator would work but it still doesn't avoid explicit None checks. This is a very subtle point but for a very common situation.

Comment: You're asking for something like: https://pypi.org/project/option/ which isn't in the std lib. Perhaps you consider that non-Pythonic? Python's natural syntax occasionally requires intermediate variables or are difficult to chain, in comparison to some other langs.

Comment: @tdelaney In this example, I am already using a very short variable name but if you imagine longer variable names, then having to do d.get('long variable name') and d['long variable name'] in the same line is verbose. My concern here is not performance, just style.